# double quote not showing in Image alt and title

Tags: magento-1.9, html

I am facing issue: On home page double quote not showing in Image alt and title on view source, But on inspect element it is showing. Anyone have suggestion so please share.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: can you please share your code in qus.?

Comment: For example: Image coming from static block :

Comment: <div class="block-title"><span style="color: #ffffff;">xxxx</span></div>
<img title="services" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/images/block/services.png"}}" alt="services" /></li>

Comment: @Ramsipl it is better to update the question instead of adding code in comment

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
src="{{media url='wysiwyg/images/block/services.png'}}"
```

in your `img`  tag instead of

```
src="{{media url="wysiwyg/images/block/services.png"}}"
```

Comment: I tried this already..but not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Inside double quote you cannot use double directly. You have to use like

```
<img title="services" src="{{media url='wysiwyg/images/block/services.png'}}" alt="services" />
```

OR

```
<img title="services" src='{{media url="wysiwyg/images/block/services.png"}}' alt="services" />
```

Comment: But Quote is coming in src attribute, Not in all alt and title(non blank)

Comment: @Ramsipl, Can you put all your code in question so we can get proper idea about your issue.